# Could a 1kHz EM field be detectably disturbed by an action potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, antennas

This might be completely off base, but I'm wondering if this would be possible.

Neurons fire action potentials that can be modeled as low-intensity (~100mV) EM pulses of 1kHz frequency (up and back in ~1ms).

I'm wondering if EM waves of matching frequency would be perturbed by neurons firing action potentials if they're in the wave path. And if so, would such a disturbance be detectable?

The setup could be something like this:

1kHZ wave generator -> neural tissue -> EM wave detector

In such setup, the detected waves would be unperturbed if no action potentials were fired, and be perturbed through destructive/constructive interference if APs were fired.

Could this work?

Comment: This is dangerously off-topic. It's not a question for physicists but for physicians. As for the physics: Electricity does disturb neurons, but not in a "good" way. Unless you know exactly what you are doing AND you are doing it SAFELY AND ETHICALLY in a controlled medical environment, you need to abstain from all experiments that mix electricity and nerve tissue. As a human being you are only few mA of electrical current away from irreversibly stopping a heart, be that your own or that of a "test subject". You don't want to have to explain to a judge what "went wrong" with your "experiment".

Comment: Not following how this is a question for medical doctors instead of physicists. I'm interested in detectability of EM waves as perturbed by small EM pulses. Of course, if this could work, all the necessary precautions would be taken.

Comment: The interaction of biological tissue with any physical environment is a matter for biology/medicine. Physics is not the right forum for this. The only reason why I am responding to this, at all, is to warn you to not underestimate the "necessary precautions" if you had any plans to work on electrophysiology experimentally. If you are serious, join an electrophysiology group at a university, they can teach you how to do this right.